# Animation "ghosting" on xxhdpi Android javafxports application

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I've written a small javafx app that animates a square moving from the top-left corner to bottom-right. It then reverses the animation and runs it continuously. On my pixel 4 (xxhdpi) the square leaves behind a trail of edges on the return trip. This does not happen on on my Nexus 7 2013 (xhdpi) or on my desktop.

Tried both the gluon plugin and also the gluon-vm plugin.

Seems related to screen pixel density . . . how do you prevent the ghosting artifacts on dense screens? Image and code below.

Pixel 4 screenshot:

[image]

Nexus 2013 Screenshot:

[image]

And the app:

```
public class StockJavaFx extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Dimension2D dimension = Services.get(DisplayService.class)
                .map(DisplayService::getDefaultDimensions)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("DisplayService"));

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(75, 75);

        Pane container = new Pane();
        container.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(dimension.getWidth(), dimension.getHeight(), Color.DARKSLATEGRAY));
        container.getChildren().add(rectangle);

        Scene scene = new Scene(container);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(750), rectangle);
        tt.setFromX(0);
        tt.setToX(dimension.getWidth() - 75);
        tt.setFromY(0);
        tt.setToY(dimension.getHeight() - 75);
        tt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        tt.setAutoReverse(true);

        FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(750), rectangle);
        ft.setFromValue(Color.ORANGERED);
        ft.setToValue(Color.CADETBLUE);
        ft.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        ft.setAutoReverse(true);

        tt.play();
        ft.play();

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with the Gluon client plugin with JavaFX 11+? See here: https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples. I've tested on my Pixel XL (density 3.5), no "ghosting" issues.

Comment: I did not know Gluon Client existed! It's not shown in the list of products on gluonhq.com, which is a curious omission. I'll experiment and update.

Comment: @JoséPereda Using Gluon Client, animation does not suffer from ghosting. Thank you! If you post a formal answer, I'll select it. Now, I have to figure out how to customize the android manifest and learn about Gluon Substrate, in general. Also, I started looking into Gluon after seeing one of your JavaFX videos on YouTube. :)

Comment: Great, good to know. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *old* Gluon `jfxmobile` plugin is more or less EOL, and it's being replaced by the new Gluon Client plugin. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin) and [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples). Detailed documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/client).

This is how you can try creating an Android app that will solve the "ghosting" issue, with some extra "small" benefits, like using Java and JavaFX 11+, GraalVM, and getting a much more performant app.
Note that the client plugin for Android is still under heavy development and it's not ready for production yet.

Before you get started, please check that you follow the prerequisites [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples#linux-and-android):

- Use a Linux machine
- Download and extract [this version](https://download2.gluonhq.com/substrate/graalvm/graalvm-svm-linux-20.1.0-ea+28.zip) of GraalVM.
- Set `GRAALVM_HOME` environment variable to the GraalVM installation directory, like:

  ```
  export GRAALVM_HOME=/opt/graalvm-svm-linux-20.1.0-ea+28
  ```
- Use Java 11, or set `export JAVA_HOME=$GRAALVM_HOME`

You can modify one of the existing samples, like [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples/tree/master/Maven/HelloGluon).

You can modify the pom to use the latest versions like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gluonhq.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellogluon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>hellogluon</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>14.0.1</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.7</attach.version>
        <client.plugin.version>0.1.22</client.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.gluonhq.hello.HelloGluon</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now you can modify the main view to add your transition:

```
public class HelloGluon extends MobileApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () -> {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(75, 75, Color.DARKSLATEGRAY);
            Pane container = new Pane(rectangle);
            container.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkslategray");

            return new View(container) {
                @Override
                protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
                    appBar.setTitleText("Gluon Mobile");
                    appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.button(e -> {
                        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(750), rectangle);
                        tt.setFromX(0);
                        tt.setToX(getWidth() - 75);
                        tt.setFromY(0);
                        tt.setToY(getHeight() - 75);
                        tt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                        tt.setAutoReverse(true);

                        FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(750), rectangle);
                        ft.setFromValue(Color.ORANGERED);
                        ft.setToValue(Color.CADETBLUE);
                        ft.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                        ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                        tt.play();
                        ft.play();
                    }));
                }
            };
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.TEAL.assignTo(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(HelloGluon.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        if (Platform.isDesktop()) {
            Dimension2D dimension2D = DisplayService.create()
                    .map(DisplayService::getDefaultDimensions)
                    .orElse(new Dimension2D(640, 480));
            scene.getWindow().setWidth(dimension2D.getWidth());
            scene.getWindow().setHeight(dimension2D.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

You can now run with your regular JDK on your machine:

```
mvn clean javafx:run
```

and verify that works fine.

If that is the case, you can now create a native image with GraalVM, also on your machine:

```
mvn clean client:build
```

This is a lengthy process, that requires usually 16 GB RAM, and a few minutes.

Once finished successfully, you can run it:

```
mvn client:run
```

It should work as expected:

[image]

Finally, you can try to build an Android native image:

```
mvn -Pandroid client:build
```

When finished, create the apk:

```
mvn -Pandroid client:package
```

It will create an apk under `target/client/aarch64-android/gvm/apk/bin/hellogluon.apk`.

Plug a device, to install and run:

```
mvn -Pandroid client:install client:run
```

[image]

Note: by default, icon assets and AndroidManifest are generated at `target/client/aarch64-android/gensrc/android`. If you want to modify either of them, you have to copy the content of this folder to `src/android`.

Comment: Lots of great detail here! Thank you very much. I'm "watching "the maven plugin and substrate projects on github. Also, following gluonhq on twitter, where they mentioned the maven client plugin last month. Where else can devs get the latest details on progress? Is it too much to hope that the android target matures by the summer?